# How to have dynamic data type variable in Java data model class?

Tags: java, json, parsing, model

An API response will send different data type value in different situation. I am using Gson parser to parse json response string. 
eg :

```
1. { "value" : 1 }
2. { "value" : "Hello" }
3. { "value" : { "name" : "name", "email" : "" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map<String, Object>` and then manually check where `value` is digit, `String` or nested `Map`

Comment: I am using gson parser library in Android project. So How can we create data model class which supports dynamic data type?